# Functional programming interfaces in Java

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, functional-programming, monads

Where can I look for a list of Java standard libraries for functional design patterns? I've heard `java.util` package contain all of data structures, but I can't find the equivalents of functional interfaces in it:

```
Monoid -> Appendable

Monad -> Flattenable

Functor -> Mapable

Applicative -> Sequencable

Arrow -> Stateful

Lens -> Damnable
```

There are also `Foldable,` `Traversable`, `Parser`, `Pipe` and so on.

Comment: Where do the function you name come from? I mean `Monoid`, `Appendable` and such. Java has some interfaces (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html), but you can define your own with `@FunctionalInterface` annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this open source project: https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava

> "Other Abstractions - monoid, semigroup, natural, random number
>   generator, reader, writer, state, input/output, parser, zipper,
>   specification based testing (quickcheck), actors, optics (lens, prism,
>   fold, traversal and others), concurrency and type conversion."